# Google Chrome crashes/freezes everything in Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS x64

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, crash, 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

I haven't been able to figure what exactly triggers this but, at certain points when I have Chrome running, my mouse cursor will suddenly start to stutter, then slow, then it won't be able to move at all.

Once everything freezes up and often times even before that, no combination of keys can get the system to reboot or shut off; nothing registers and the only way I've been able to reboot is by forcing everything down with the power button.

I've seen recommendations on here to either disable hardware acceleration or upgrade the NVIDIA driver but neither of those solutions has worked for me thus far.

Is anyone experiencing the same problem and does anybody have a fix for this?

Lastly, I had this exact same issue with 14.04 and 15.04 but not with 15.10. Since upgrading to 16.04 recently, I've encountered this problem again multiple times. Also, if it matters at all, I'm using an AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor × 8 and a GeForce GTX 660/PCIe/SSE2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem with the regular version 16.04.  Getting pretty sick of having to restart every 10 minutes or so.  :(

Comment: I am experiencing this too.

Comment: I have similar issues mostly with chrome when using other applications too. Possibly not enough RAM -, i've got 4GB only. When using chrome alone it works fine.

Comment: @PeterM I have 32GB of RAM. I don't think RAM is the problem here.

Comment: Same issue here with i7 4790, 32GB RAM and default Ubuntu nvidia 361.42 drivers installed via driver applet. Chrome would lock up momentarily on some sites and sometimes during tab change. dmesg shows Chrome segfault so guess this is a Chrome issue but the same doesn't happen on Arch install and Chromium on same machine.

Comment: Does ctrl + alt + f1 work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP of this unanswered question hasn't signed on in more than a year. Making it an abandoned question as per guidelines in:  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/4056/what-to-do-when-users-have-been-inactive-for-months-and-their-question-remain-op